# Simple JS filter (first tab active + fade effects)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple filter of the content, but I need 2 little things to improve it:

1. How can I make first tab active by default? So I am not showing all content.
2. Is there a way I can add a simple fade in/fade out effect when clicking on one of the tabs?

Here is my `HTML` and `JS`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
    var filters = {};
    //when a link in the filters div is clicked...  
    $('#filters a').click(function(e){  
        e.preventDefault();  
        filters[$(this).parent().attr('class')] = $(this).attr('id');  
        var show = $('#content ul li').filter(function(){ 
            for(k in filters)
                if(
                   filters.hasOwnProperty(k) &&
                   !$(this).hasClass(filters[k])
                )
                return false;
            return true;
        });
        show.show();
        $('#content ul li').not(show).hide();
        $('pre:first').html(JSON.stringify(filters));     
    });  
});
```

```html
<div id='filters'>
<p class="f1" >
    <a href='#' id='mon'>Monday</a>
    <a href='#' id='tue'>Tuesday</a>
    <a href='#' id='wed'>Wednesday</a>
    <a href='#' id='thur'>Thursday</a>
    <a href='#' id='allitems'>All</a>
</p>
</div>  


    <div id='content'>  
        <ul>  
            <li class='mon allitems'>monday content goes here</li>  
            <li class='tue allitems'>tuesday content goes here</li>  
            <li class='wed allitems'>wednesday content goes here</li>  
            <li class='thur allitems'>thursdaycontent goes here</li>   
        </ul>  
</div>
```

Comment: Please mark an answer as your "accepted" one ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First answer**:
You can call the click event for the first link with `$('#mon').click();` in this way you will trigger the click event and the function will run.

**Second answer**:
jQuery have the `fadeIn() fadeOut()` functions. Use them insted of `show()`

http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/py3ezk9y/

Answer (score 1):

#### Filter with fadein/fadeout

I think a much simpler way to filter this, is to use a (not anonymous) function, which you can call from every where:

```
var $listToFilter = $('#content ul');    
var $allElements = $listToFilter.find('li');
var filterCache = {};

function filterElements (filterClass) {
    var $elementsToFilter;

    if(filterCache.hasOwnProperty(filterClass)) {
        $elementsToFilter = filterCache[filterClass];
    } else {
        $elementsToFilter = $listToFilter.find('.' + filterClass);
        filterCache[filterClass] = $elementsToFilter;
    }

    $allElements.not($elementsToFilter).hide();
    $elementsToFilter.fadeIn();
}

filterElements('mon');
```

Than for the click event you can use this function, too:

```
$('#filters a').click(function () {
    var filterClass = $(this).attr('id');

    filterElements(filterClass);
});
```

#### Fiddel

For the hole example please have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wachri/edw67wx4/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
var filters = {};
//when a link in the filters div is clicked...
$('#content ul li').not(':first').hide();
  $('#filters a').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      filters[$(this).parent().attr('class')] = $(this).attr('id');
      var show = $('#content ul li').filter(function(){
          for(k in filters)
              if(
                 filters.hasOwnProperty(k) &&
                 !$(this).hasClass(filters[k])
              )
              return false;
          return true;
      });
      $('#content ul li').not(show).hide();
      show.fadeIn();
      $('pre:first').html(JSON.stringify(filters));
  });
});
```